# Unable to view pdf output in lyx

Tags: 16.04, latex, lyx

Unable to view pdf output in lyx

It says "successful preview of the format: PDF(pdflatex)". I have removed lyx and reinstalled it but the problem still remains.

Comment: Just a reminder 16.04 reaches end of standard support on April 22 2021. You may want to think about upgrading to 18.04 or 20.04. End of Stand Support means no more support or updates. You may not ask questions here either as 16.04 will be off topic. If you sign up for ESM you can still get security patches but that is all.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I Will upgrade soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installed evince-gtk package to view PStoPDF

[Link to the package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=evince-gtk)